# Hook into Rails model Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to create a customer generator in my rails 4 application. I ran

```
rails g generator bootstrap
```

This created some files in `lib/generators/bootstrap`. including `bootstrap_generator.rb`

```
class BootstrapGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
end
```

I would like this generator to hook into when I run `rake g model ...`. How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: You'll probably want to create a new generator for this. There's probably a way to do this via monkey-patching the current Rails generators, but that's not how most handle this. Also github is down as I'm writing this, so I can't point you to any files :(

Comment: I would really prefer to not monkey patch anything.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do with this new generator?  If you're trying to alter the way that models are generated, then you need to alter the template for models, not create a whole new generator.

Comment: When someone runs `rails g ...` I want to create an additional file based on that model similar to the way that rspec creates a corresponding model_spec.rb file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is not clean but working solution, anyway:

**config/application.rb**

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm             :concerns # to get run our generator under ActiveRecord
      g.test_framework  :rspec
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/generators/rails/concerns/concerns_generator.rb**

```
require 'rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator'

module Rails
  module Generators

    hide_namespace 'concerns'

    class ConcernsGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator
      source_root "#{base_root}/active_record/model/templates"

      def create_concern_file
        create_file "app/models/concerns/#{file_name}_concern.rb", <<-FILE
      class #{class_name}Concern

      end
        FILE
      end

      def create_concern_spec
        create_file "spec/models/#{file_name}_concern_spec.rb", <<-FILE
      require 'spec_helper'

      describe #{class_name}Concern
        pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
      end
        FILE
      end

    end
  end
end
```

which is give us:

```
$ rails g model Product name:string description:text
      invoke  concerns
      create    db/migrate/20131005122831_create_products.rb
      create    app/models/product.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/product_spec.rb
      create    app/models/concerns/product_concern.rb
      create    spec/models/product_concern_spec.rb
```

Comment: Okay, how did you figure out how to do that? Is there a definitive guide I missed on the rails site?

Comment: Its was deep analys how that sub-system work. Every thing was just around source code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/model_generator.rb

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rails generators have changed too much between rails 3 and 4, so these railscasts should still be helpful:

- [#216 Generators in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3)
- [#218 Making Generators in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3)